two highlighted lines per plot in ggplot multiplot
I have created the following chart that you can see below. But I would like to reduce the number of plots by having two highlighted lines in each plot (so I can delate half of the subplots). So that for instance Agriculture and Construction are highlighted in one single plot with the other gray lines in the background.

I guess the idea would be to make couples of every two Industry series from the data below. But I can't figure out how then in ggplot I would differentiate between them in the same subplot.
the data I am using looks like this:
dput(df_annual)
structure(list(Industry = c("Agriculture", "Mining", "Utilities", 
"Construction", "Manufacturing", "Wholesale trade", "Retail trade", 
"Transportation and warehousing", "Information", "FIRE", "Professional and busines sservices", 
"Education and healthcare", "Entertainment, Accommodation, and food services", 
"Otherservices", "Petroleum and coal products", "Aggregate Markup (weighted by value added)", 
"Agriculture", "Mining", "Utilities", "Construction", "Manufacturing", 
"Wholesale trade", "Retail trade", "Transportation and warehousing", 
"Information", "FIRE", "Professional and busines sservices", 
"Education and healthcare", "Entertainment, Accommodation, and food services", 
"Otherservices", "Petroleum and coal products", "Aggregate Markup (weighted by value added)", 
"Agriculture", "Mining", "Utilities", "Construction", "Manufacturing", 
"Wholesale trade", "Retail trade", "Transportation and warehousing", 
"Information", "FIRE", "Professional and busines sservices", 
"Education and healthcare", "Entertainment, Accommodation, and food services", 
"Otherservices", "Petroleum and coal products", "Aggregate Markup (weighted by value added)", 
"Agriculture", "Mining", "Utilities", "Construction", "Manufacturing", 
"Wholesale trade", "Retail trade", "Transportation and warehousing", 
"Information", "FIRE", "Professional and busines sservices", 
"Education and healthcare", "Entertainment, Accommodation, and food services", 
"Otherservices", "Petroleum and coal products", "Aggregate Markup (weighted by value added)", 
"Agriculture", "Mining", "Utilities", "Construction", "Manufacturing", 
"Wholesale trade", "Retail trade", "Transportation and warehousing", 
"Information", "FIRE", "Professional and busines sservices", 
"Education and healthcare", "Entertainment, Accommodation, and food services", 
"Otherservices", "Petroleum and coal products", "Aggregate Markup (weighted by value added)"
), value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
-4.16899022725953, -3.16048739095132, 2.26615125120156, 0.66130884603661, 
-0.0280915175999513, 2.83955145388273, 1.0360196924704, -1.02176623498684, 
3.82132039562726, -0.336373727020167, -0.423101133276901, 0.162838968005144, 
0.202636027998032, -0.130655654963285, 0.484757543749409, 0.345797906863748, 
-6.19581465100466, -7.76170158802538, 9.8323710595107, -0.384612600833956, 
-0.142319217128792, 5.36608584813379, 2.06086341070106, -3.96206889404121, 
2.69441070658506, -0.270586167227105, -1.72408562953159, -1.91182207972596, 
-3.09849125788884, -2.40236202213844, -10.4483984657011, 0.644164935123387, 
5.05288723613821, 7.26564778080908, 6.16490973408088, -1.27550822039797, 
-0.420179493561609, 1.11895934710035, 1.42772550145728, -0.587421638026028, 
0.60164150449748, -0.490330403219696, -1.95109398370057, -0.916492053203161, 
-1.40945477592939, -1.74435002828741, -1.61195956200604, 0.311268220225386, 
7.79558265461643, 8.59069593264387, 5.82758955116995, -1.90794919946671, 
0.0574902177623432, 0.646474887329734, 1.01097219864939, 0.888814212065392, 
0.529917989609702, 1.77421737752929, -2.58667857085753, -1.39478160549774, 
-0.392924607564787, -1.37729956885558, -0.724198001834994, 0.890255993161343
), date = structure(c(17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
17532, 17897, 17897, 17897, 17897, 17897, 17897, 17897, 17897, 
17897, 17897, 17897, 17897, 17897, 17897, 17897, 17897, 18262, 
18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 
18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18628, 18628, 18628, 
18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 
18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 
18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 
18993, 18993), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -80L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

The code I am using so far look like this:
df_annual %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,linetype="solid", size=.25) +
  geom_point(data=df_annual %>% 
               group_by(Industry) %>% 
               slice_max(date),
             aes(x=date, y=value, color=Industry),shape=16) +
  geom_line(aes(x=date, y=value, color=Industry), size = 1) +
  gghighlight(use_direct_label = FALSE,
              unhighlighted_params = list(linewidth = 0.5, colour = alpha("grey85", 1))) +
  geom_text(data=df_annual %>% 
              group_by(Industry) %>% 
              slice_max(date),
            aes(x=date, y=value, color=Industry, label = round(value, digits = 1)),
            hjust = -.5, vjust = .5, size=4, family=font, fontface="bold") +
  #scale_color_met_d(name="Redon") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-10,-5,0,5,10),
                     labels = c("","","0","","")
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~ Industry) +
  # facet_wrap(~  factor(Industry, levels=c('Agriculture,forestry,fishing,andhunting','Mining','Utilities','Construction', 
  #                                          'Manufacturing','Wholesaletrade', 'Retailtrade', 'Transportationandwarehousing', 'Information',
  #                                          'Finance,insurance,realestate,rental,andleasing', 'Professionalandbusinessservices',
  #                                          'Educationalservices,healthcare,andsocialassistance', 'Arts,entertainment,recreation,accommodation,andfoodservices',
  #                                          'Otherservices,exceptgovernment','Aggregate'
  #  ))) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_text(color=txt_col, size=10),
    strip.text.x = element_text(face="bold", size = 15),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust=.9,size=80, color=txt_col,lineheight=2.8, face="bold", margin=margin(20,0,30,0)),
    # plot.subtitle = element_markdown(hjust=.5,size=48, color=txt_col,lineheight = 1, margin=margin(10,0,30,0)),
    # plot.caption = element_markdown(hjust=.5, margin=margin(60,0,0,0), size=8, color=txt_col, lineheight = 1.2),
    plot.caption.position = "plot",
    plot.background = element_rect(color=bg, fill=bg),
    plot.margin = margin(10,10,10,10),
    legend.position = "none",
    legend.title = element_text(face="bold")
  )


Your code is a little complexe, here is an minimal example  inspire by https://ggplot2-book.org/facet#sec-group-vs-facet . `df <- data.frame(
x = rnorm(120, c(0, 2, 4)),
y = rnorm(120, c(1, 2, 1)),
z = letters[1:3]
) %>% mutate (z2 = case_when( z == "a" ~ "a and b",
z == "b" ~ "a and b",
z == "c" ~ "c only"))
df2 <- dplyr::select(df, -z, -z2)#
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
geom_point(data = df2, colour = "grey70") +
geom_point(aes(colour = z)) +
facet_wrap(~z2)`

which data should I use to run your code? Thanks!

I made an answer. But in my previous comment, my code should be reproducible since  I defined df. You might want to charge library(tidyverse)

I did not use gghighlight, but a trick inspired by  ggplot2: Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis (3e) ` ; involving unselecting the faceting variable.
I made a variable IndustryPair to group the Industry in groups of two. It is the faceting variable. I also had to use data = . for some geom elements to supply IndustryPair. I had to comment out some theme or visual element, since some variable like font are undefined in your example.
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: le package 'ggplot2' a été compilé avec la version R 4.3.3

df_annual = structure(list(Industry = c("Agriculture", "Mining", "Utilities", 
                                        "Construction", "Manufacturing", "Wholesale trade", "Retail trade", 
                                        "Transportation and warehousing", "Information", "FIRE", "Professional and busines sservices", 
                                        "Education and healthcare", "Entertainment, Accommodation, and food services", 
                                        "Otherservices", "Petroleum and coal products", "Aggregate Markup (weighted by value added)", 
                                        "Agriculture", "Mining", "Utilities", "Construction", "Manufacturing", 
                                        "Wholesale trade", "Retail trade", "Transportation and warehousing", 
                                        "Information", "FIRE", "Professional and busines sservices", 
                                        "Education and healthcare", "Entertainment, Accommodation, and food services", 
                                        "Otherservices", "Petroleum and coal products", "Aggregate Markup (weighted by value added)", 
                                        "Agriculture", "Mining", "Utilities", "Construction", "Manufacturing", 
                                        "Wholesale trade", "Retail trade", "Transportation and warehousing", 
                                        "Information", "FIRE", "Professional and busines sservices", 
                                        "Education and healthcare", "Entertainment, Accommodation, and food services", 
                                        "Otherservices", "Petroleum and coal products", "Aggregate Markup (weighted by value added)", 
                                        "Agriculture", "Mining", "Utilities", "Construction", "Manufacturing", 
                                        "Wholesale trade", "Retail trade", "Transportation and warehousing", 
                                        "Information", "FIRE", "Professional and busines sservices", 
                                        "Education and healthcare", "Entertainment, Accommodation, and food services", 
                                        "Otherservices", "Petroleum and coal products", "Aggregate Markup (weighted by value added)", 
                                        "Agriculture", "Mining", "Utilities", "Construction", "Manufacturing", 
                                        "Wholesale trade", "Retail trade", "Transportation and warehousing", 
                                        "Information", "FIRE", "Professional and busines sservices", 
                                        "Education and healthcare", "Entertainment, Accommodation, and food services", 
                                        "Otherservices", "Petroleum and coal products", "Aggregate Markup (weighted by value added)"
), value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
             -4.16899022725953, -3.16048739095132, 2.26615125120156, 0.66130884603661, 
             -0.0280915175999513, 2.83955145388273, 1.0360196924704, -1.02176623498684, 
             3.82132039562726, -0.336373727020167, -0.423101133276901, 0.162838968005144, 
             0.202636027998032, -0.130655654963285, 0.484757543749409, 0.345797906863748, 
             -6.19581465100466, -7.76170158802538, 9.8323710595107, -0.384612600833956, 
             -0.142319217128792, 5.36608584813379, 2.06086341070106, -3.96206889404121, 
             2.69441070658506, -0.270586167227105, -1.72408562953159, -1.91182207972596, 
             -3.09849125788884, -2.40236202213844, -10.4483984657011, 0.644164935123387, 
             5.05288723613821, 7.26564778080908, 6.16490973408088, -1.27550822039797, 
             -0.420179493561609, 1.11895934710035, 1.42772550145728, -0.587421638026028, 
             0.60164150449748, -0.490330403219696, -1.95109398370057, -0.916492053203161, 
             -1.40945477592939, -1.74435002828741, -1.61195956200604, 0.311268220225386, 
             7.79558265461643, 8.59069593264387, 5.82758955116995, -1.90794919946671, 
             0.0574902177623432, 0.646474887329734, 1.01097219864939, 0.888814212065392, 
             0.529917989609702, 1.77421737752929, -2.58667857085753, -1.39478160549774, 
             -0.392924607564787, -1.37729956885558, -0.724198001834994, 0.890255993161343
), date = structure(c(17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
                      17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
                      17532, 17897, 17897, 17897, 17897, 17897, 17897, 17897, 17897, 
                      17897, 17897, 17897, 17897, 17897, 17897, 17897, 17897, 18262, 
                      18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 
                      18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18628, 18628, 18628, 
                      18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 
                      18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 
                      18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 
                      18993, 18993), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -80L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                          "tbl", "data.frame"))

df_annual %>% group_by(Industry) %>%  mutate(IndustryID= cur_group_id() ) %>% 
  mutate(IndustryPair = paste0("Industry group", as.character( IndustryID%/%2 ) ) ) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,linetype="solid", size=.25) +
  geom_point(data= . %>%  #select(-IndustryPair) %>% 
               group_by(Industry) %>% 
               slice_max(date),
             aes(x=date, y=value, color=Industry),shape=16) +
  geom_line(aes(x=date, y=value, color=Industry), linewidth = 2) +
  geom_line( data= . %>% select(-IndustryPair), aes(x=date, y=value, group= Industry), col ="grey", linewidth = 1) +
  #gghighlight(use_direct_label = FALSE,
 #             unhighlighted_params = list(linewidth = 0.5, colour = alpha("grey85", 1))) +
  geom_text(data=. %>% 
              group_by(Industry) %>% 
              slice_max(date),
            aes(x=date, y=value, color=Industry, label = round(value, digits = 1)),
            hjust = -.5, vjust = .5, size=4, #family=font,
            fontface="bold") +
  #scale_color_met_d(name="Redon") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-10,-5,0,5,10),
                     labels = c("","","0","","")
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~ IndustryPair) +
  # facet_wrap(~  factor(Industry, levels=c('Agriculture,forestry,fishing,andhunting','Mining','Utilities','Construction', 
  #                                          'Manufacturing','Wholesaletrade', 'Retailtrade', 'Transportationandwarehousing', 'Information',
  #                                          'Finance,insurance,realestate,rental,andleasing', 'Professionalandbusinessservices',
  #                                          'Educationalservices,healthcare,andsocialassistance', 'Arts,entertainment,recreation,accommodation,andfoodservices',
  #                                          'Otherservices,exceptgovernment','Aggregate'
  #  ))) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    #axis.text = element_text(color=txt_col, size=10),
    strip.text.x = element_text(face="bold", size = 15),
    #plot.title = element_text(hjust=.9,size=80, color=txt_col,lineheight=2.8, face="bold", margin=margin(20,0,30,0)),
    # plot.subtitle = element_markdown(hjust=.5,size=48, color=txt_col,lineheight = 1, margin=margin(10,0,30,0)),
    # plot.caption = element_markdown(hjust=.5, margin=margin(60,0,0,0), size=8, color=txt_col, lineheight = 1.2),
    plot.caption.position = "plot",
    #plot.background = element_rect(color=bg, fill=bg),
    plot.margin = margin(10,10,10,10),
    legend.position = "none",
    legend.title = element_text(face="bold")
  )
#> Warning: Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.


Created on 2024-06-13 with reprex v2.1.0

Great, thanks!
The only problem with this solution is that the highlighted lines are behind the grey ones. Is there any way to bring them to the front?

Make the call with "grey" first, the next geom_line() call will be printed "in front"
